# SFML : drawing from different files

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on a SFML project that contains several different files and classes. The problem is : in every file, there is some drawing, and the sf::RenderWindow* defined in the main file seems to be out of scope here, therefore I can't link these drawing with the main window. I've tried to redefine sf::RenderWindow in every header files, and it doesn't work as well (a black screen appear and disappear promptly). The error was : Access violation reading location. But when I group everything in one file, things work well but it looks really messy.

I also found this question asked on another forum, and the answers were "using reference and external method", which is a bit vague to me. Any help on this linking problem would be appreciated :(

Comment: Please post some code which highlights the behavior you get.

Comment: BTW, just from reading, I think you have some classes in separate files for some functionality. If so, you may need to pass a reference of the Window object to those classes (probably in the constructor) and then use that reference to update the contents in the Window.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that answer meant something like:

```
void draw_in_class (sf::RenderWindow* window){
    window->draw(...);
}
```

in class, and then you can use 'draw_in_class' in main:

```
#include"class.h"

... // Define sf::RenderWindow here

draw_in_class(&window);
```

Comment: Actually I figured it out just a week after posting my question :) Passing a pointer to the window as function argument is the way to go, not another window object. Thanks for your answer anyway :)